# NetworkX: 'Graph'

Tags: python

I have the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "net.py", line 6, in <module>
    G=nx.Graph()
  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Graph'
```

when I run this code:

```
import networkx as nx
import pylab as py
blue_edges = [('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), ('B', 'E'), ('E', 'F')]
red_edges = [('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('C', 'E'), ('D', 'E'), ('D', 'F')]

G=nx.Graph() #define G
G.add_edges_from(blue_edges)
G.add_edges_from(red_edges)

pos = {'A':(0,0), 'B':(1,1), 'C':(1,-1), 'D':(2,1), 'E':(2,-1), 'F':(3,0)}

nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos, edgelist = [], node_color = 'k')
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos, nodelist = [], edgelist = blue_edges, edge_color = 'b')
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos, nodelist = [], edgelist = red_edges, edge_color = 'r')
```

I use python 2.7 and 1.11 networkx library all within anaconda

Comment: What is your python file called, did you call it `networkx.py`?

Comment: Try printing `nx.__file__`.  Did you perhaps create your own file named `networkx.py`?

Comment: without the file it is called net.py

Comment: the code works for me when I added plt.figure() before nx.draw_networkx(); did you try restarting the kernel, renaming the file and importing networkx?